# how to parse out date time from a string and match with a given format

Tags: c#

My datetime value is stored in the column as 12/03/2013 12:00 am, I am trying to parse out the date from a different column which is a string so i check to see if the datetime is a valid date. I can not figure out the format, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm tt doesnt seem to make the condition true.

```
string[] format = new string[] { "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm tt" };
DateTime datetime;
//12/03/2013 12:00 am
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(userFilters.FilterValue, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out datetime))
{
  DateEntered = datetime;
}
```

**EDIT**

In the column the value is stored as **2012-07-02 13:08:39.347**

Comment: Not clear what is your problem. The data that you want to parse is not 12/03/2013 12:00 am, but the date in another column and is stored as a string? If so how is stored the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a sample date-string as commented in your code:

```
12/03/2013 12:00 am
```

Why do start with the year in your format string?

This should work:

```
string[] format = new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt" };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

1.if your date string is `12/03/2013 12:00 am` as provided in comments, you should start with `month` but not with `year`.

2.you need to use `/`  as seperator but not `-`.

3.you need to use capital `MM` to represent `month` as small `mm` is used to represent `minutes`

**Solution:**

```
string[] format = new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt" };
DateTime datetime;
//12/03/2013 12:00 am  
if (DateTime.TryPars eExact(userFilters.FilterValue, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out datetime))
{
 DateEntered = datetime;
}
```